# How do I configure Service Fabric Placement Constraints?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I want to be able to configure placement constraints based on different node types (i.e. FrontEnd, BackEnd). Can I do this per-environment, so that in my test/local cluster there are no constraints, but on my production environments there is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can! The official docs describe a way to do this via code, but you can also do so with the service manifest files directly to get default & per-environment configuration. There is a [blog post](https://brentdacodemonkey.wordpress.com/2016/09/11/placement-constraints-with-service-fabric/) you can follow (found it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39435829/2078866)).

Comment: Here's the official documentation on PlacementConstraints, I found this helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-cluster-description#node-properties-and-placement-constraints

Comment: FYI - unfortunately the above doesn't work for Placement Policies (e.g. to constrain by fault domains - e.g. data center). For this, as far as I can tell, you must use code/scripting