# Provision my service fabric application to run on specific nodes on the cluster

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-on-premises

I am setting up a cluster.  Maybe 2 depending on what kind of answer I can get here.  Basically I have 5 servers, and I am planning on setting up 8 nodes on each one for 40 total nodes.  I plan on load balancing 5 of them for the out side API calls.  doing this I need to control that app so it only works on those 5 nodes, and I want the other apps to use all of them as they need.. So can I control what specific nodes on a cluster an app sticks to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I configure Service Fabric Placement Constraints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40558124/how-do-i-configure-service-fabric-placement-constraints)

Comment: that's just talking about configuration from dev to productions.  it doesn't talk about how to setup so one application resides on one sent of nodes, and others are on all of them.. but I might have found how to do it with node type.. I will fallow up if that is the answer

Comment: You can place constraints using the nodetype, nodetypename or nodename. So if you have just one nodetype you could use nodename. More details found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-cluster-description#node-properties-and-placement-constraints. Do note the closed issues on the bottom of that pages, there is an answered question about restraints based on the node name.

Comment: By the way, the linked question answers do talk about node types so it does talk about apps residing in different node (sets)