# Service fabric: constraint a service to run alone on some nodes

Tags: service, azure-service-fabric

I have node type fe and 5 services that runs on it. I want 1 of these services to run alone on some of the nodes (on those node only this service will run and no other service).

My first idea was placement constraints but that means I need to create a new node type and to create new Vmss's.
Is there a way of doing it without creating a new node type? Maybe tagging some nodes in the vmss?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I configure Service Fabric Placement Constraints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40558124/how-do-i-configure-service-fabric-placement-constraints)

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts thanks for the comment but it doesn't answer my question, I'm looking for a way to make some nodes with the same type run only 1 service and the other node will run the other services.

Comment: How would you handle node down time? Say a cluster with 5 nodes. U use 2 nodes to run a specific service. The other 3 nodes are running the 4 different services. The first 2 nodes go down? What do you want do do next?  Stop running the first service? 
My point being, service fabric has placement constraints for a reason, just update your cluster with a secondary node type

Comment: It would be good to get a bit of detail about what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I have 5 services running on those node type, few of them might consume high CPU, I want to make sure my WebApi always runs alone on few of those nodes to avoid “Noisy neighbor” with the other busy services to make sure I don’t have any downtime or delay in the customer facing WebApi

Comment: Have you setup resource governance? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-resource-governance

Comment: thanks for the refrence. If I understand correctly, using the resource governance means I have to set all services to be governed and not only the service I want to save from noisy neighbor, right? I prefer not to limit resource usage of other services because it might lead to some other performance issues