# Azure Service Fabric Multi-Tenancy with microservice

Tags: asp.net, azure, multi-tenant, microservices

I  want  to  develop   the  Micro-service   apps    using   Azure Service Fabric Multi-Tenant ,   for   this   i   already   Configured   Active   Directive   with   Multi   Domain   dev,Prod   etc.

I  did   not  get  any   sample   reference    which   will  help   me   to   get  start   this   topic

I   already   followed   this   link

[Azure Service Fabric Multi-Tenancy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35247726/azure-service-fabric-multi-tenancy)

But   not   find   any   sample   reference

Comment: i   also    follow    some  Programming   style   on   azure   service   febric         https://books.google.co.in/books?id=iMg_DAAAQBAJ&pg=PT445&lpg=PT445&dq=Azure+Service+Fabric+Multi-Tenancy&source=bl&ots=8YTTw6RroN&sig=oMDPqy7N1TIvqfYXVJ5gLTocUR4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwioxpzJ0_rOAhVFuY8KHZGvAgsQ6AEIRzAH#v=onepage&q=Azure%20Service%20Fabric%20Multi-Tenancy&f=false

Comment: Instead of partitioning the service by tenant, can you send the tenant identification as part of the message, so that the code underlying the service can execute on the context of a tenant. Kindly share your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is going to help you. But I believe you should follow this process

1. Create Service Fabric package for your application (using msbuild or VS).
2. Upload package into Service Fabric Image Store through api ([example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-remove-applications)). This will create a base *ApplicationType* for you which you will use later.
3. Now from that *ApplicationType* create a new application Instance using [New-ServiceFabricApplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/servicefabric/vlatest/new-servicefabricapplication) command. Just specify different *ApplicationName* and use same *ApplicationTypeName*. If you need to override some parameters, specify *ApplicationParameter*.
4. You can create as many Instances as you need from original *ApplicationType*.