# one service fabric cluster or multiple cluster?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am migrating several of my cloud service web/worker roles into service fabric.

There will be many (around 5+) service fabric services (stateless or stateful). Shall we put all of them into one service fabric cluster, or multiple clusters? Is there best practice on cluster plan?

Also, I will add multi-tenant support on my service. per this post [Service Fabric multi-tenant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34616020/service-fabric-multi-tenant?lq=1), I can choose application instance per customer pattern.

I am wondering if it is good idea to choose cluster per customer pattern?

Answer (score 5):

It depends on your requirements per-tenant, but generally it is better to have a single cluster with multiple applications and services:

- A single cluster is much easier to manage than multiple clusters.
- Service Fabric was designed to host and manage a large number of applications and services in a single cluster.
- Multiple services in a single cluster allows you to utilize your cluster resources much more efficiently and use Service Fabric's [resource balancing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-introduction/) to manage resources effectively.
- Standing up a new cluster, depending on size, can take 30 minutes or more. Creating application instances in a cluster takes seconds.

Comment: Thanks Vaclav! Will go single cluster solution.